Is there a built-in feature to sync the editing position between two windows of the same file?
I often split two windows of the same file to edit,
so that it's easier, like I can implement a function
in a window and check the long comments somewhere in
another window.
Sometimes, after I did something in one window, I would
like to 'sync' the two windows, that is, to move the
editing position of the other window to the same place.
I think this can be accomplished by firstly move to the
other window, then close it with a :q, then create
a new window with :sp, and I can get two windows
with the same position.
However, I am wondering that maybe there is a straightforward
built-in feature for that. I checked the :help but didn't find
something. I searched in the Internet, and found people asking
about sync-scrolling, i.e. :set scrollbind, which is good
but not what I am looking for.
I understand that this can be accomplished by some user-defined
functions and might be available in some plugins, but I am curious
whether there is a built-in method for that.

You can put all the individual steps in a single mapping.

One option is to use the fact that lower-case marks are bound to buffers. So you mark the place you want to sync to in one window, switch to the other, and go to the mark. The following example sequence uses the i mark:
mi
Ctrl-wCtrl-w
'i

Well, s/files/buffers, but this is a neat idea!
